# Why React Element don exist in JMeter HTTP Response Body even if I enabled "Retrive All Embedded Resources"?

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to create a load test that accesses a webpage and then accesses an element in that web page and I've already enabled "Retrieve All Embedded Resources"

the actual page HTML looks like this:

```
<body class="" data-gr-c-s-loaded="true" style="">
    <div id="react-root">
        <div class="main">
            <div class="alert-container"></div>
            <div class="loader-bg" style="display: none;">
                <div class="loader-bar">Hi</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

the response on JMeter is

```
<!--some header and stuff-->

<body class="">
  <div id="react-root"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: Current configuration]

How can I configure JMeter so I can get the element inside the "react-root" div?

Comment: Please share these things to narrow down the issue: 1) What happens when you remove "408" response timeout and re-run? 2) Paste the request & response from both recorded and replayed iterations 3) Post the "Basic" tab as well for this request

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Apache JMeter project main page](https://jmeter.apache.org/):

> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, **JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages.** Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

So JMeter will not execute any React code which is in the server's response therefore if some parts of the page are being loaded by JavaScript - JMeter will not retrieve them.

However you should be able to record the relevant request(s) using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder). You might want to put the request(s) under the [Parallel Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter/) which executes it's children in parallel properly simulating simultaneous asynchronous nature of [React AJAX requests](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html)